# How to get the full path of script where is path getting from method which located in another folder from class?

Tags: python, path, operating-system

Let's say so

package1/
    `main.py` == here i'm calling from Utils class that must give me the path of this file where i call it

package2/
    `utils.py` = which must contain method that return path where they call it

from main.py wanna get path of that main.py from packages Utils

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you aware of ˋ__file__ˋ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Utils class like this:

```
class Utils:
    """docstring for Utils"""

    def getRootPath():
        pass

    def get_current_path(self):
        return os.path.realpath(self.filePath)


    def __init__(self, filePath):
        super(Utils, self).__init__()
        self.filePath = filePath
```

When you initialize your class somewhere just put the name of script where you init you Utils class like this:

```
utils = Utils(os.path.basename(__file__))
print(utils.get_current_path())
```

If you wanna get the dirname where you call it so make another method or replace it with

```
return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(self.filePath))
```

While you wait someone faster you will do it yourself, especially when morons ask so what do you want to do